# Suzuki Freewind XF650 Start issues

Tags: motorcycle, starting, suzuki

Motorcycle starts fine several times and once it started it runs perfectly. But every now and again it will take about 2-5 mins to start, does not push start or start with starter button.

Sometimes it will start perfectly once and then 2nd time it has issue and then not again, sometimes it will have the issue 2 or 3 times in a row. And then days will pass without any issues. The starter motor turns perfectly with every start attempt (whether successful or unsuccessful)

Fuel has been ridden out and refilled several times, bike has had a major serviced since the issue started. It has absolutely no issue once it started.

Comment: I dont know a whole lot about bikes, probably next to nothing... But I had the "exact" same problem with my car in the past, and a friend had a car that would die once it was warmed up... both of our issues turned out to be a gunked up camshaft sensor, just needed cleaned... but I also cleaned up my crank shaft sensor just for good measure.